# Is there a way to query IIS Logs?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, iis

Is there a way to query IIS Logs to get which user accessed which page and at what time?

What actions were performed on the page?

Answer (score 3):

You can't query IIS logs from within SharePoint. But there is a tool from Microsoft that can help you to analyze these logs: [LogParser](http://www.microsoft.com/en-eg/download/details.aspx?id=24659)

And here is a Technet article with the detailed steps: [IIS Log parsing for SharePoint](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31388.iis-log-parsing-for-sharepoint.aspx)